MongoDB - Perform an upsert on a nested collection
I need to update multiple documents in a single operation.
I have a structure that looks like (simplified)
 public class LEDataEntity
{
  public Guid Guid { get; set; }
  public List<PaymentDetails> PaymentDetails { get; set; } = [];

}
 public class PaymentDetails
 {
     public DateTime PaymentDateTime { get; set; }
     public string? PaymentReference { get; set; }
     public decimal PaymentAmount { get; set; }
    
}

When I perform the update, I'm providing a list of LEDataEntity PK values to match on, and  a PaymentDetails node. I need to perform an UPSERT on the paymentDetails collection.  Matching on paymentDetails.PaymentReference.
When a matching payment reference value is found in the collection, I want to replace the FundingDetails node with the value being passed in.  When the collection doesn't contain a matching PaymentReference node, I want to add it to the list.
Here's the (.NET) code I have
 var filter =builder.In(i=>i.Guid, myLEGuids);     
updateDefinition = Builders<LEDataEntity>.Update.Combine(
           Builders<LEDataEntity>.Update.Set("PaymentDetails.$[elem]", paymentDetails),
           Builders<LEDataEntity>.Update.Push("PaymentDetails", paymentDetails)
               .Set(i=>i.PaymentDateTime, paymentDetails.PaymentDateTime)
        


var arrayFilters = new List<ArrayFilterDefinition>
             {
                 new BsonDocumentArrayFilterDefinition<BsonDocument>(new BsonDocument("elem.PaymentReference", request.PaymentReference))
             };
        
         updateOptions = new UpdateOptions { ArrayFilters = arrayFilters };
           var updateResult = await this.Collection.UpdateManyAsync(this.ClientSessionHandle, filter, updateDefinition, updateOptions, cancellationToken);
  

But when I attempt to perform an update, that should result in  the PaymentDetails node getting inserted, I get the following

"Updating the path 'PaymentDetails' would create a conflict at
'PaymentDetails'"

I'm not sure where to go from here.

Upserts on an array of subdocuments are one of the more complicated situations when updating MongoDB documents. Instead of running a normal update that sets static values, you need to perform an update with aggregation pipeline that transforms the documents that match the filter.
In this case, the pipeline contains two $set stages:

The first one asserts that the PaymentDetails property is not null but at least an empty array.
The second one tries to find an element with a matching PaymentReference value;

If there is an element, it maps the existing array items and replaces the one that has a matching PaymentReference value with the new object.
If there is no element, it adds the new object to the array



The following C# code assumes that there are 3 GUIDs (guid1, guid2, guid3) that you want to filter for and shows a sample on how to perform the update:
var newPaymentDetails = new PaymentDetails()
{
    PaymentDateTime = new DateTime(2024, 05, 06, 12, 34, 56, DateTimeKind.Utc),
    PaymentAmount = 789.12m,
    PaymentReference = "C",
};

var filter = Builders<LEDataEntity>.Filter.In(x => x.Guid, [guid1, guid2, guid3]);
var pipeline = new EmptyPipelineDefinition<LEDataEntity>()
    .Set(x => new LEDataEntity()
    {
        PaymentDetails = (x.PaymentDetails ?? new List<PaymentDetails>()),
    })
    .Set(x => new LEDataEntity()
    {
        PaymentDetails = x.PaymentDetails.Any(y => y.PaymentReference == newPaymentDetails.PaymentReference)
        ? x.PaymentDetails.Select(y => y.PaymentReference == newPaymentDetails.PaymentReference ? newPaymentDetails : y).ToList()
        : x.PaymentDetails.Union(new List<PaymentDetails>() { newPaymentDetails }).ToList(),
    });

var update = Builders<LEDataEntity>.Update.Pipeline(pipeline);
await coll.UpdateManyAsync(filter, update, null, default);


APPENDIX: Documents before & after the update
Before running the update, there are 3 documents with the following content (ids, GUIDs & dates omitted for brevity):
[
    {
      "PaymentDetails": null
    },
    {
      "PaymentDetails": [
        {
          "PaymentReference": "A",
          "PaymentAmount": "123.45"
        },
        {
          "PaymentReference": "B",
          "PaymentAmount": "456.78"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "PaymentDetails": [
        {
          "PaymentReference": "A",
          "PaymentAmount": "123.45"
        },
        {
          "PaymentReference": "C",
          "PaymentAmount": "456.78"
        }
      ]
    }

]

After the update, the documents look as follows:
[
    {
      "PaymentDetails": [
        {
          "PaymentReference": "C",
          "PaymentAmount": "789.12"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "PaymentDetails": [
        {
          "PaymentReference": "A",
          "PaymentAmount": "123.45"
        },
        {
          "PaymentReference": "B",
          "PaymentAmount": "456.78"
        },
        {
          "PaymentReference": "C",
          "PaymentAmount": "789.12"
        }
      ]
    }, 
    {
      "PaymentDetails": [
        {
          "PaymentReference": "A",
          "PaymentAmount": "123.45"
        },
        {
          "PaymentReference": "C",
          "PaymentAmount": "789.12"
        }
      ]
    }
]


APPENDIX: Generated aggregation pipeline
MongoDB C# Driver generates the following aggregation pipeline for the update:
[
  {
    $set: {
      PaymentDetails: {
        $ifNull: ["$PaymentDetails", []]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      PaymentDetails: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $anyElementTrue: {
              $map: {
                input: "$PaymentDetails",
                as: "y",
                in: {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$y.PaymentReference",
                    "C"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          },
          then: {
            $map: {
              input: "$PaymentDetails",
              as: "y",
              in: {
                $cond: {
                  if: {
                    $eq: [
                      "$$y.PaymentReference",
                      "C"
                    ]
                  },
                  then: {
                    PaymentDateTime: ISODate(
                      "2024-05-06T12:34:56Z"
                    ),
                    PaymentReference: "C",
                    PaymentAmount: "789.12"
                  },
                  else: "$$y"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          else: {
            $setUnion: [
              "$PaymentDetails",
              [
                {
                  PaymentDateTime: ISODate(
                    "2024-05-06T12:34:56Z"
                  ),
                  PaymentReference: "C",
                  PaymentAmount: "789.12"
                }
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

